# Unmarshalling an array of objects and arrays

Tags: java, xml-serialization, jaxb

Hi I'm very new to XML, and webservices but I'm recieving XML from a SOAP webservice that looks kind of like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <ArrayOfCreditCardSettlement xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Borgun.Library.Common">
      <ns0:CreditCardSettlement xmlns="http://Borgun.Services.Gateway/2010/04/Settlement" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Borgun.Library.Common" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:msgns="http://Borgun.Services.Gateway/2010/04/Settlement" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Borgun.Library.Common" xmlns:ns1="http://j2ee.netbeans.org/wsdl/BorgunTestBPEL/entrypoint_getSettlements">
        <a:amexAmount>**</a:amexAmount>
        <a:amount>**</a:amount>
        <a:batches>
          <a:CreditCardBatch>
            <a:batchdate>***</a:batchdate>
            <a:batchnumber>***</a:batchnumber>
            <a:currencyCode>***</a:currencyCode>
            <a:merchantnumber>***</a:merchantnumber>
            <a:settlementRunNumber>***</a:settlementRunNumber>
            <a:settlementdate>***</a:settlementdate>
            <a:slips>*</a:slips>
            <a:sum>***</a:sum>
          </a:CreditCardBatch>
          .
          . 
           more batches

        <a:deductionItems>
            <a:CreditCardSettlementDeduction>
               <a:amount>***</a:amount>
               <a:code>**</a:code>
               <a:currencyCode>**</a:currencyCode>
               <a:merchantnumber>***</a:merchantnumber>
               <a:settlementrunnumber>***</a:settlementrunnumber>
               <a:text>***</a:text>
            </a:CreditCardSettlementDeduction>
         .
         . more deductionitems 
         </ns0:CreditCardSettlement>
         .
         . more Settlements
```

I used Netbeans to create a jaxb binding which seems to work

```
 try
    {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("is.skyrr.jaxbbinding");
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

        Object o = (Object) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("....response3.xml"));


    } catch (JAXBException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(TestDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

The binding is generated and has "ArrayOfCreditCardSettlement", "CreditCardSettlement" and objectfactory etc..

Now the only thing i can do here is cast to JAXBElement

that is `            JAXBElement a = (JAXBElement) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("...response3.xml"));

Maybe that's what i'm supposed to have but from that how am i supposed to use this?

I want that array/list to use but I've just got no idea what to do next.

AdditionalInfo:
 the binding is generated from an xsd

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ArrayOfCreditCardSettlement", propOrder = {
"creditCardSettlement"})
  public class ArrayOfCreditCardSettlement {

@XmlElement(name = "CreditCardSettlement", nillable = true)
protected List<CreditCardSettlement> creditCardSettlement;

public List<CreditCardSettlement> getCreditCardSettlement() {
    if (creditCardSettlement == null) {
        creditCardSettlement = new ArrayList<CreditCardSettlement>();
    }
    return this.creditCardSettlement;
}
```

similar for the CreditCardSettlement class.

the object factory has XMLElementDecl's explicitly naming the namespace and so on and forth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JAXBElement has a value and that should be an `ArrayOfCreditCardSettlement` object.

Here is a code sample that could give some hints: 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/UnmarshalltoJAXBElement.htm

Comment: thank you very much, the value thing just completely evaded my sight

Answer (score 1):

1. I'm pretty sure you can't have a Collection as the top level object.
2. Have you set up your POJOs and your ObjectFactory?  You should be able to unmarshal directly into your target object. e.g.

   ```
   CreditCardSettlementContainer ccsc = (CreditCardSettlementContainer) unmarshaller.unmarshal(yourFile);
   ```

Reference: [JAXB tutorial](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing2.html)

On the other hand if you're just getting started I highly recommend [Simple XML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/)  It's ***much*** easier to understand and use, not to mention being more flexible.

Comment: thank you for the link, I was trying to unmarshal directly into the target object but for whatever reason it didn't work.

I don't have the luxury of choosing SimpleXML but thanks for your response